# Scala: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list

Tags: scala, list, recursion, functional-programming

I have two Scala lists like this:

```
taskProduct: List[(TaskOrder, Product)] = TSK1,PRD1 :: TSK1,PRD2 :. TSK1,PRD3 :: TSK2,PRD1 :: TSK2,PRD2 :: TSK2,PRD3 ::Nil

humanPhysical: List[(Human, Physical)] = H1,PHYS1 :: H1,PHYS2 :: H2,PHYS1 :: H2,PHYS2 :: H3,PHYS3 :: H3,PHYS4 :: H4,PHYS3 :: H4,PHYS4 :: Nil // Physical is a short for Physical Resource
```

I am coding function that associates each element of the list `taskProduct` to an element of the list `humanPhysical`.

The `taskProduct` list will be iterated and everytime the algorithm associates the element in question to another element of the list `humanPhysical`, this element of `taskProduct` will be discarded.

At the final of each cycle, if there is still some element in the `taskProduct` list, the function has to run again and the list `humanPhysical` will be sent with the default values (the values were sent in the beginning).

By now I have this function:

```
def createSchedules(taskProduct: List[(TaskOrder, Product)], humanPhysical: List[(Human, Physical)], previousTime: Duration): List[TaskSchedule] = {
    def createSchedules2(taskProduct: List[(TaskOrder, Product)], humanPhysical: List[(Human, Physical)], previousTime: Duration, humanPhysicalOccupied: List[String], Product)]): List[TaskSchedule] = taskProduct match {
      case (a, b) :: tail =>
        val listExistsHuman = humanPhysical.map(x => humanPhysicalOccupied.contains(x._1.id))
        val existsHuman = listExistsHuman.filter(x => x == true).length
        if (existsHuman > 0) println("occupied by human resources")
        else {
          val listExistsPhysical = humanPhysical.map(x => humanPhysicalOccupied.contains(x._2.id))
          val existsPhysical = listExistsPhysical.filter(x => x == true).length
          if (existsPhysical > 0) println("occupied by physical resources")
          else {
            val physicalOfTheHuman = humanPhysical.head._2.post
            val physicalResourcedAcceptedByThisTask = a.physicalRes.map(pr => pr.post)
            if (!physicalResourcedAcceptedByThisTask.contains(physicalOfTheHuman)) println("task doesnt accept physical resource")
            else {
              createSchedules2(tail, humanPhysical.tail, previousTime + a.time, humanPhysical.head._1.id :: humanPhysical.head._2.id :: humanPhysicalOccupied, taskProduct.head :: tasksScheduled)
            }
          }
        }
        createSchedules2(taskProduct, humanPhysical.tail, previousTime + a.time, humanPhysicalOccupied, tasksScheduled)
      case Nil => Nil
    }
    createSchedules2(taskProduct, humanPhysical, 0 minute, List.empty, List.empty)
  }
```

But this gives me an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list` on the line `val physicalOfTheHuman = humanPhysical.head._2.post`.

What kind of tweak should I do to my solution to make it work?

Comment: You may wanna add definitions for you classes, in case somebody wants to try your code (TaskOrder, Product, Human, Physical, TaskSchedule)

Comment: Try debugging. [Conditional breakpoints](https://dzone.com/articles/effective-debugging) could help.

Comment: Seems like your code could use some abstractions.